# how to convert Class to Instance Object

Tags: java, reflection

take a look at my code....

```
    Class<?> c = Class.forName("PerformanceInvokeService");

    Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("monthlyTestCal", new Class[] {
            String.class, Date.class });
    Object ret = m.invoke("PerformanceInvokeService", new Object[] {
            "some string", new Date() });
    System.out.println(ret);
```

i execute this and its thrown an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

i think, because i don't create an instance of c (likes...new PerformanceInvokeService())
and i don't know how to create it

somebody help?

sorry for my english...

thanks

Comment: Check this link. Has some good points on how to go about fixing it http://ourcraft.wordpress.com/2009/01/23/object-is-not-an-instance-of-declaring-class/

Comment: I edited the tags to better categorize the question.  You should bear in mind that each tag stands on its own; they don't form a sentence.  (It doesn't make sense to group a question about "instance" with other questions about "instance", for example.  But it *does* make sense to group a question about Java with other questions about Java.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `PerformanceInvokeService` has an accessible default constructor, you can create a new instance using:

```
Object instance = c.newInstance();
```

You can then pass that to the method invocation:

```
Object ret = m.invoke(instance, new Object[] { "some string", new Date() });
```

If there is no accessible default constructor, then you'll have to find a constructor that you can use by using reflection.

Answer (score 1):

`Class` has a `newInstance()` method that you can call to create an instance of the class using its default constructor.  Or, you can call `getConstructor()` or `getConstructors()` to find a constructor that takes the right kind of arguments, and then call `newInstance()` on the `Constructor` object, passing the construction arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
Object myInstance = c.newInstance();
```

This will call the default constructor and create a new object. Then you can use this as the first argument in

```
m.invoke()
```

Answer (score 0):

On newer versions of Java try this:

- Assuming `resultClass` stands for `Class<T> resultClass`
- Reason for doing so is that `Class.newInstance` is now deprecated (since Java 9)

```
try {
  content.add(resultClass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance());
} catch (Exception e) {
  log.catching(e);
}
```

P.S. Perhaps catching with `Exception` is excessive.